# c# Using BackGroundWorker Class to update Static WinForm Control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have three Classes:

1. A Form Class (MyForm) with a Button and a Panel (MyPanel).
2. A BackGroundWorker Class (DataGridViewLoader).
3. A DataGridView Class (MyDataGridView).

The reason why I chose three separate classes is to prevent too much code in my Form Class.

In my Form Class I want to initiate the BackGroundWorker which should create and fill my DataGridView. Once it completes it should add the instance of my DataGridView to my Panel.

I have a few questions seeing that I am still learning to code:

1. This possible?
2. Is this the best or most elegant way to do it?
3. If it is the best way, how do I add the DataGridView to the (static) Panel?
4. If it is not the best way, how should I tackle this?

This is what I have at the moment:

Code in MyForm Class:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewLoader worker = new DataGridViewLoader();
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Code in DataGridViewLoader Class:

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{    
     MyDataGridView myDataGridView = new MyDataGridView();
     BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();       
     myBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
     myBindingSource.DataSource = MyDataTable;
}
```

Seeing that MyPanel is static, I have seen in other questions posted that one needs to make use of invoke.

```
private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MyForm.myPanel.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         //Add datagridview to my panel.
         MyForm.myPanel.Add(myDataGridView);        

    }));
}
```

However I am facing this error:

```
"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyForm.myPanel'"
```

Comment: You can't access GUI elements (`DataGrid`) from a `BackgroundWorker`, so it's not possible. But the compiler error you get is a different story.

Comment: You need to do this declaration outside the DoWork method : MyDataGridView myDataGridView = null;

Comment: @dymanoid : You are wrong.  The BackgroundWorkerCompleted is an Event and can access the controls.  I've done it lots of times before.  The event has to be registered in the Form class.

Comment: @jdweng, see - the OP creates a `DataGrid` in the `DoWork` handler. This won't do.

Comment: You can't tell from posted code which class the code is located.  The posting isn't showing where the register occurred.  An event does not have to be inside the class.

Comment: @jdweng, you are right: The MyDataGridView myDataGridView should indeed be out side the DoWork method. I will update that.

Comment: It still not clear how to add the DataGridView to my Panel...

Comment: Create the DGV before running the BGW. In `DoWork`, generate a DataTable. Return the DataTable as the `[DoWorkEventArgs].Result (`e.Result`)` of `DoWork`. In the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, check `e.Error` and `e.Cancelled`, then read `e.Result` (of type `object`) as a `DataTable` (cast it) and assign it to the DGV's DataSource (or a support BindingSource). The `RunWorkerCompleted` event is raised in the UI Thread, you don't need to `Invoke` anything there. Not sure what a *static Panel* is. If you mean classes declared as `static`, don't.

Comment: @Jimi, you need to explain "Return the DataTable as the [DoWorkEventArgs].Result (e.Result) of DoWork." to me.

Comment: When the BGW has completed its work, you can pass the results of this work to the `e.Result` property. The value of this property can be read as the    [`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs) of the `RunWorkerCompleted` event (see the Remarks section there). The same applies to the `RunWorkerAsync(Object)` overload, where the `Object` you pass to the method become the `DoWorkEventArgs.Arguments` object. That's how you pass values from the UI Thread to the background thread and vice-versa.

Comment: @Jimi, earlier you said "The RunWorkerCompleted event is raised in the UI Thread". That is not the case. My DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted methods are in my DataGridViewLoader Class. Not in my UI (Form Class).

Comment: Your `DataGridViewLoader` is a BackGroundWorker (`DataGridViewLoader worker = new DataGridViewLoader();  worker.RunWorkerAsync();`). This class is initiaized and used in a `Button.Click` event handler, thus from the Main UI (STA)Thread. The `RunWorkerCompleted` event is always raised in the thread that called `RunWorkerAsync()`. If you're running this Form from another thread, then you made a mistake that you need to correct.